# How to define the grammar for TeX/LaTeX and Makefile?

Tags: makefile, latex, grammar, tex

Both are technologies that are expressed via languages full of macros, but in a more technical terms, what is the kind of grammar and how to describe their own properties ?

*I'm not interested in a graphical representation, by properties I mean a descriptive phrase about this subject, so please don't just go for a BNF/EBNF oriented response full of arcs and graphs .*

I assume that both are context-free grammars, but this is a big family of grammars, there is a way to describe this 2 in a more precise way ?

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about theories of natural language processing and might be better asked on [Linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Thomas more like a question about programming/technical languages, I don't know how many programmers could possibly visit that branch of SO, I also don't think that an experienced linguistic could possibly help nearly as much as an experienced programmer   .

Answer (score 1):

TeX can change the [meaning of characters](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/catcode) at run time, so it's not context free.

Comment: wait, the meaning of "macro based language" can't be translated in "you can simply perform a text substitution" to get the new meaning of the keyword ?

Comment: TeX definitely makes extensive use of macros, but unfortunately it's more complicated than that. In other words, it's not entirely macro based according to your definition.

Answer (score 1):

**Is my language Context-Free?**

I believe that every useful language ends up being Turing-complete, reflexive, etc.

Fortunately that is not the end of the story.

Most of the parser generation tools (yacc, antler, etc) process up to context-free grammars (CFG).

So we divide the language processing problem in 3 steps:

1. Build an over-generating CFG; this is the "syntactical" part that constitutes a solid base where we add the other components,
2. Add "semantic" constraints  (with some extra syntactic and semantic constraints)
3. main semantics ( static semantics, pragmatics, attributive semantics, etc)

Writing a context-free grammar is a very standard way of speaking about all the languages!
It is a very clear and didactic notation for languages!! (and sometimes is not telling all the truth).

When We say that "is not context-free, is Turing-complete, ..." you can translate it to "you can count with lots of *semantic* extra work" :)

**How can I speak about it?**

Many choices available. I like to do a subset of the following:

1. Write a clear semantic oriented CFG
2. for each symbol (T or NT) add/define a set of semantic attributes
3. for each production rule: add syntactic/semantic constraints predicates
4. for each production rule: add a set equations to define the values of the attributes
5. for each production rule: add a English explanation, examples, etc